# Pycharm not using nosetests config file

Tags: python, pycharm, nose, nosetests

PyCharm doesn't load any settings from the nose config file while python's interpreter does. How can I enable PyCharm to use the config file? I'd also like to understand why.

*It's very important that the settings come **from the config file** and **not only params** on my instance of PyCharm. My provided set up only has 3 files, but I will eventually be using the answer to share testing settings collaboratively.*

Here's the setup:

```
~/PycharmProjects/Testing/test_suite.py
~/PycharmProjects/Testing/unnecessary_math.py
~/nose.cfg
```

When running via the interpreter(outside of PyCharm) the "nose.cfg" settings are recognized and ran giving:

```
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:Testing marcs$ nosetests -s .
nose.config: INFO: Ignoring files matching ['^\\.', '^_', '^setup\\.py$']
Doctest: unnecessary_math.divide ... ok
Doctest: unnecessary_math.multiply ... ok
Starting Test
['/Users/marcs/nose.cfg']
test_suite.test_numbers_0_4 ... ok
test_suite.test_num_4_4_4_4 ... ok
Ending Test

----------------------------------------------------------------------
XML: nosetests.xml
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.008s

OK
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:Testing marcs$
```

When running from PyCharm I get this output

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 61446 --file /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/noserunner.py /Users/marcs/PycharmProjects/Testing/ -s
Testing started at 5:36 AM ...
pydev debugger: process 10464 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 133.881)




Starting Test
['/Users/marcs/nose.cfg']
..

..
Ending Test

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.023s

OK


Process finished with exit code 0
```

So from what I can see it looks like PyCharm's environment is cognizant of the nose.cfg file but for some reason chooses not to load it. I don't know why.

I've included the source code of the files below:

~/nose.cfg

```
[nosetests]
verbosity=3
with-doctest=1
with-xunit=1
```

test_suite.py

```
from unnecessary_math import multiply
from nose.tools import assert_equals
import nose.config as config

def setup_module():
    print "Starting Test"
    print config.all_config_files()

def teardown_module():
    print "Ending Test"

def test_numbers_0_4():
    assert_equals(multiply(0,4), 0)

def test_num_4_4_4_4():
    assert_equals(multiply(4,4,4,4), 256)
```

unnecessary_math.py

```
def multiply(*args):
    """
        This function multiplies any number of integers together
        'Given a list of numbers it will give you their commutative product'
        >>> multiply(4,4)
        16
        >>> multiply(4,4,4,4)
        256
        >>>
    """
    product = 1
    for arg in args:
        product = product * arg
    return product

def divide(a,b):
    """
        This function divides a by b
        'b divides a'
        >>> divide(4,4)
        1
        >>> divide(8,2)
        4
        >>>
        >>> divide(5,2)
        2
        >>>
    """
    return a/b
```

Comment: I have looked back into this. I still don't have an answer but I was able to replicate the same behavior in straight nosetests (outside of PyCharm) when I keep the same file structure and add "__ init __.py" while running the nosetests from within the same folder. When running from outside the folder it works normally but within the folder it behaves just like PyCharm (ignoring the cfg file).  I attempted to do the same from PyCharm to see if that fixes the issue and it has not.

Answer (score 5):

I would try explicitly specifying `--config=/home/YOUR_USERNAME/nose.cfg` in pycharm, as "Additional Arguments".

Comment: Thanks Oleksiy for what could be a solution for some. I forgot to mention that I need the settings to come from the config file and not only the params one can put in explicity via the PyCharm "params" field (ie: I don't want to block whatever additional params people in a team setting wish to put in on their own machines). I've went ahead and updated my post above to reflect that criterion.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. I think it should but it doesn't. I have to put in the full explicit location '/Users/marcs/nose.cfg' for it to work using PyCharm's param field. Is there some setting I haven't set?

Comment: I think it would make sense to make `nose.cfg` a part of the project in `~/PycharmProjects/Testing/`

Comment: I think you're right. Unfortunately, I have searched for how to do that and haven't found a way. If you know please share and if it works I'll mark it as the correct answer :)